# How should a Christian object to those who say Paradise may be a little boring?

Tags: heaven

From time to time while reading fiction or poetry or whatever I stumble on a certain kind of, so to say, 'satire' of the Paradise the main point of which is that the everlasting live would be meaningless and boring.
For example

a) we would pursue the same pleasures again and again and this would lead to a comic effect. (see Julian Barnes 'The History of the World in 9 1/2 Chapters')

b) other people in Paradise may tend to alienate a certain person, as well, as angels may tend to look down upon ordinary people and thus suffering would not end. (See Tiger Lillies  'Heaven to Hell' song from 'Brothel to the Cemetary' album)

c) We can be separated with our closest relatives as they can be sent to Hell instead (see Mark Twain 'Captain Stormfield's Visit to Heaven')

How do I object?

Comment: Simple: if they say that they wouldn't enjoy Paradise, don't argue with them. They may be correct. That's the point of Hell, a place reserved for those who have no interest in praising God.

Comment: @SanJacinto - the "point of Hell" is to punish the Devil and his angels. *People* sent there are those who have rebelled against God, too.

Comment: @warren O I'm afraid I don't follow you argument! So those writers do not go to Hell directly?

Comment: @warren that's my point.

Comment: @SanJacinto - I know, I was adding the back-context for the (from our perspective) 'original purpose' of Hell

Comment: Please see ken boa's sense and nonsense about heaven and hell, for an extended hermeneutic on the topic. Also keep in mind that heaven is temporary until the general resurection.

Comment: @aceinthehole These are bad news then! I expected Heaven to last forever. I do not want to feel like a tourist thrown out from his hotel just because some tour operator gone bankrupt! If this is indeed so I appreciate some quotations from the Book about that and I do regret having learnt that that late!

Comment: @Alex, I not sure if understand your tourist analogy. However, again I'd direct you at the [book](http://www.amazon.com/Sense-Nonsense-about-Heaven-Hell/dp/0310254280) for a very detailed explanation, or perhaps the entire chapter of [1 Corinthians 15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15&version=NIV). [Here](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12792a.htm) is a  catholic outline, I'd direct you at the new testament subheading.

Comment: @Alex, the catholic encyclopedia link, contains many scriptural references btw, if you are interested.

Comment: @aceinthehole O thank you Sir, indeed! Interestingly while I as astonished at that temporarity of Hell I told so my wife but it so happened she already knew that! She must have an account here too then I think she may have a gold maybe badge!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we could envision exactly what Heaven is going to be like, it wouldn't be Heaven, just as if we could comprehend God, He wouldn't be God.

Just as man should not create (in their own minds) a God made in their image, but understand that man was made in God's image.  So too we must not make Heaven in the image of the earth, but understand that earth reflects in part the image of Heaven.

When we think of playing a harp on a cloud in heaven and singing for eternity, I admit that it doesn't really sound like heaven--even though I love to sing and I think harps are really awesome.

Let me address your three points:

a) experience the same pleasures over and over again:  This is an earthly perspective.  There is no indication that we will be bound to pleasures that will lose their impact and result in boredom.  Rather, God being God certainly would have the capacity to give us eternal joy.  *In fact, if God is infinite, it will take an eternity to get to know Him fully.*

b) Looking down on others in Heaven:  Angels certainly have a special place in Heaven, having never known sin.  However, we have a special place as well, for we are the only ones for whom God the Son died.  God never became an angel, but He did become a man.  God's glory will be sufficiently wonderful to drown out all sin.  There will be no jealousy as we will all be overflowing with joy.

c) Separation from people we love:  Wherever you go in the world, it becomes evident that we were created for relationships.  However, we were not ultimately created for relationships just with each other, but for the ultimate relationship with the Ultimate Being.  So, our relationships with others are only shadows of the greater relationship we will experience.  Our joy of union with God will be far greater than all other unions.

**God created us for Himself, and He will not merely satisfy us, but will give us abundant joy for eternity.**  God is infinitely able to do immeasurably more than we ask or imagine.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that those authors do not understand heaven.

The point of heaven is worshipping God. [Biblical Belief]

Even if heaven lost all its angels, even if heaven lost all the elect, so long as God is there, heaven will be heaven. [Personal belief.]

How can that be?

Consider the most exciting biography you've ever read; consider the most fascinating interview you've ever watched. Consider how you were completely drawn into the other person's life and were simply in awe.

Worshipping God is an infinitely greater version of that. What is greater? (1) re-watching the Bulls two three-peat runs, (2) reading about Alexander's military conquests or (3) listening to God talk about the flood in the times of Noah, the 10 plagues in the time of Moses, the fire from haven in the days of Elijah, and all the hidden battles fought between the angels we haven't even heard of?

What would be more fascinating? (1) understanding the internals of an F22 jet, (2) comprehending the balance of nature or (3) listening to God talk about how he created the universe in a week?

What will be more heart moving? (1) the "love" of Twilight, (2) the "love" of Romeo / Juliet, or (3) the love of all the unseen things Christ endured on the cross?

Those who fail to understand heaven often (1) judge heaven from the perspective of human opinion, whereas (2) to understand the glory of heaven, we must first seek to understand the attributes of God.

### References:

What happened on the cross?

- http://www.heartcrymissionary.com/resources/ebooks/76-the-cross-of-christ
- http://www.heartcrymissionary.com/resources/ebooks/78-the-meaning-of-the-cross
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QbWYFsI2G8

Comment: This is most probably true, Sir, but then you see I am a man of ignorance so I would appreciate any quotations from the Book to that effect. And I have a question what is 'unseen things' Christ could saw while on the cross as you say? Do you mean like a horror movie style things to which He anyway gave all his love?

Comment: @Alex: added references for what happened on the cross

Comment: @user1694 O wow very interesting. I've only read the 1st one so far thanks very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

As Saint Paul stated this:

> However, as it is written:
>
> “What no eye has seen,
>       what no ear has heard, and what no human mind has conceived”[a]—
>       the things God has prepared for those who love him—

(1 Corinthians 2, 9)

a) So if someone tries to picture the state of Heaven with wordly terms, he would certainly create some caricature. This state is not just pursuing pleasures it is being filled with love of God, who is infinite. We can't get bored of it.

b) If God came down from Heaven and became man, how can anyone "look down" upon another. This is satanic pride. Christ, the saints and angels are full of compassion and love for us. Even if they achieved more than us, they will never "look down", because they are free from pride.

c) This is the hardest of the problems for me, but you must note, that God loves people much more that you. So you can't be more merciful for sinners than He is.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, Sir! One question though I have maybe I shall put it as a separate question here but nevertheless how is it angels are free from pride what have made them free from pride. I mean I have no doubts they are free from pride as you are saying but what would be the proof? Lucifier was not free from pride and some of his friends, too. How we can say all the others are free from pride hmmm

Comment: Because they didn't fall. If Lucifer and his angels fell because of pride, but other angels didn't, then we can infer, they didn't sin with pride.

I don't however know much about nature of angels. I know, that saintly people, even here on earth don't look down on sinners but treat them with compassion. When I confessed my sin to a very saintly monk, he said 'poor you', and I felt it was sincere compassion for me and he didn't condemn me at all.

Comment: I see Sir! Alas as you mentoned monks alas I always wanted to go to them to confess and yet I feel so much disgust at seeing them I can't do that. This is alas maybe I shall work at that out

Comment: re 1 Cor 2:9 -- Wish I could vote this down.  Please read that verse in context, you cut off "... these things God has revealed to us through the Spirit."  Paul is not referring to heaven, he is referring to the gospel of Jesus Christ, which has now been revealed.  I appreciate your heart in answering, just want to make sure that verse is understood in context.

Comment: @Randy Syring You know, Sir, I then shall vote down for you! I have voted up but now I can vote down for you. Hope that's not blasphemous gonna do that right now.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's trite — and I don't believe at all that heaven will be boring — but even if it is "boring", that sure beats the alternative. Indifference isn't an option.

Ultimately, though, I'd like to see people motivated out of love, rather than fear. Find something for them to work towards, rather than run from.

Comment: O wow Sir that was a laconic answer an very good at that! Indeed better to wait for a train then to know it's not coming! I did upvote this precise answer of yours!

Answer (score 1):

We were created to be in a relationship with God, and that will not be boring.  It will be more real and exciting than amything in this life.  When John described heaven, in the book of Revelation, he didn't have the words to describe it.

I think it was someone who asked Billy Graham if his pet dog would be in heaven.  He said, that if his pet was necessary for his happiness, it would be there, but he suspected that the glory of God would eclipse that desire for a pet.  (I should find that exact quote and reference.  Here it is: “God will prepare everything for our perfect happiness in heaven, and if it takes my dog being there, I believe he'll be there”  (Googled "Billy Graham quotes about dogs"))

If you're looking for depictions of heaven in literature, I recommend "The Great Divorce" by CS Lewis.  It has a picture of both hell and heaven, and hell is boring and unsatisfactory, heaven is exciting and real.

Comment: Ah Sir many thanks especially as you mention the revrend C.S. Lewis. I've read by him PERELANDRA! And also about martians and about univercity and about till we have faces that one was strange and mere christianity and srewtape letters or who he was. But great divorce not yet! I'm going to read it now! Alas! It all shall be as you say but what if one will be disappointed though? Like a child waiting for a present receiving not what he wanted alas then

Comment: If we were disappointed, then God would not be God.  God created a great diversity on this world for our pleasure, and knows what we want and need.  I have no worries, and I don't expect boring floating on clouds and taking harp lessons!

Comment: As Current93 my favorite group sings 'I have seen this world as the great disappointment'. This contradicts to what you're saying hmm

Comment: THIS world is a disappointment, in some ways, but heaven? The disappointments of this world are because of our broken relationship with God, our sin.  Take the wonderful parts of this world and make it so much better that we don't have the words to describe it (as the apostle John was trying to do), add in things we can't even begin to imagine, and combine it with the relationship with God we were made for.  If that is disappointing, then God is not the God described by Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing no one has mentioned so far is that its not just heaven, but a **new heavens and new earth** (Rev 21:1,2).  Not only will we have a relationship with God to pursue but we will have a creation unstained by the corruption of the fall.  We will also have all the human intuition and wisdom that we can muster to improve upon and explore that second creation (assuming, of course, that God intends us to work & subdue in the second creation as he intended us to work in the first).

Most importantly, we will do all of this with pure holiness, in a place where there isn't even the temptation to sin.

I, for one, am looking very forward to it!

Comment: Ah Sir I'm afraid there's a disappointemnt fo us, Sir! I have just received a comment to this my question that Heaven is a temporary thing until some 'general resurrecttion'. It's like then I imagine a ticket to Disneyland like 'valid until GR'. I personally can't believe that but shal find out more and will be back to you. Hope, they reconsider!